# How to properly use the ORDER BY clause in MyBatis(and How to make it work)?

Tags: sql-order-by, mybatis, resultset, ibatis

By working on a Java EE application, I currently use Apache iBatis/Google MyBatis to manage CRUD operations on database.
In some cases, I need to use aggregate functions, so I am forced to use **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** clauses together.
From Toad/PL/SQL, I'm normally able to get an *ordered* list of results;
Simply by adding "ORDER BY" to MyBatis configuration xmls, I'm still unable to get an *ordered* resultset.

I am still looking for some (simple) example.

Some snippet code below:

```
<select id="someId" parameterType="map" resultType="MyBean">
    SELECT a.FIELD1 AS f1, 
           a.FIELD2 AS f2, 
           b.FIELD1 AS f3, 
           b.FIELD2 AS f4,
           NVL(b.FIELD-NULL, '0') as f5 -- Here I use Nvl() aggregate function

    FROM TABLE-1 a, 
         TABLE-2 b

    WHERE a.ID = b.ID
    AND a.FIELD3 = b.FIELD3

    -- By using aggregate function, I must use 'group by' clause too

    GROUP BY
          a.FIELD1,
          b.FIELD2

    ORDER BY
          a.ANOTHER-FIELD /* 'order by' clause is ignored! */ 
</select>
```

Someone who knows the answer?

Comment: As far as I know, It should work. Can you provide the input tables, expected output table, actual output table?

Comment: Execute the query and see the result in another sql client first.